# export/import module not working typescript

Tags: javascript, import, module, typescript, export

I have this module called Area in folder models/area_getter.ts:

```
export module Area {
    interface iGetAreas {
        _areasList: Array < any > ;
        _areas: KnockoutObservableArray < string > ;
        getAreas(geonameId: string): void;
    }



    export abstract class AreaGetter implements iGetAreas {
        _areasList: Array < any > = [];
        _areas = ko.observableArray([]);
        _selectedAreaName: KnockoutObservable < string > ;
        _selectedAreaGeonameId: KnockoutObservable < string > ;
        _type: Area.Type;

        constructor(type: Area.Type) {
            this._type = type;
            this._selectedAreaGeonameId = ko.observable('');
            this._selectedAreaName = ko.observable('');
            this._selectedAreaName.subscribe((newValue) => {
                console.log(newValue);
                console.log(this._selectedAreaGeonameId() + "      " + this._selectedAreaName());
            });
        }

        getAreas = (geonameId: any): void => {
            this.showLoadingIcon();
            this._areasList = [];
            $.ajax({
                url: `http://api.geonames.org/children?geonameId=${geonameId}&username=elion`
            }).then((allAreasXML) => {
                this.hideLoadingIcon();
                var allAreasJSON = xml2json(allAreasXML);
                var allAreas = JSON.parse(allAreasJSON);
                if (allAreas.geonames.length) {
                    for (var index = 1; index < allAreas.geonames.length - 1; index++) {
                        this._areasList.push(allAreas.geonames[index].geoname);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (allAreas.geonames.geoname) {
                        this._areasList.push(allAreas.geonames.geoname);
                    } else {
                        this._areasList.push({
                            name: 'Any',
                            geonameId: 0
                        });
                    }
                }
                this._areas(this._areasList);

                if (this._type === Area.Type.Region) {
                    this._initiateRegionSelect();
                }
            });
        }

            _initiateRegionSelect = () => {
            $('#region-select').multiselect({
                buttonWidth: '100%',
                buttonContainer: '<div style="height: 64px;" />',
                buttonClass: 'none',
                nonSelectedText: "Select Region",
                onChange: (option, checked) => {
                    var values = [];
                    $('#region-select option').each(function() {
                        if ($(this).val() !== option.val()) {
                            values.push($(this).val());
                        }
                    });
                    $('#region-select').multiselect('deselect', values);
                    $('#region-select').next().removeClass("open").addClass("closed");
                    this._selectedAreaGeonameId(option.val());
                    this._selectedAreaName(option.text());
                }
            });
        }

            showLoadingIcon = () => {
            if (this._type === Area.Type.Town) {
                $("#town-div span.multiselect-selected-text").css("visibility", "hidden");
                $("#town-icon").addClass('special');
                $("#town-icon").css("background", "url(assets/gifs/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat");
                $("#town-icon").css("background-size", "100%");
            } else if (this._type === Area.Type.Region) {
                $("#region-div span.multiselect-selected-text").css("visibility", "hidden");
                $("#region-icon").addClass('special');
                $("#region-icon").css("background", "url(assets/gifs/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat");
                $("#region-icon").css("background-size", "100%");
            } else if (this._type === Area.Type.Suburb) {
                $("#suburb-div span.multiselect-selected-text").css("visibility", "hidden");
                $("#suburb-icon").addClass('special');
                $("#suburb-icon").css("background", "url(assets/gifs/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat");
                $("#suburb-icon").css("background-size", "100%");
            }
        }

            hideLoadingIcon = () => {
            if (this._type === Area.Type.Town) {
                $("#town-div span.multiselect-selected-text").css("visibility", "visible");
                $("#town-icon").removeClass('special');
                $("#town-icon").css("background", "transparent");
                $("#town-icon").css("background-size", "100%");
            } else if (this._type === Area.Type.Region) {
                $("#region-div span.multiselect-selected-text").css("visibility", "visible");
                $("#region-icon").removeClass('special');
                $("#region-icon").css("background", "transparent");
                $("#region-icon").css("background-size", "100%");
            } else if (this._type === Area.Type.Suburb) {
                $("#suburb-div span.multiselect-selected-text").css("visibility", "visible");
                $("#suburb-icon").removeClass('special');
                $("#suburb-icon").css("background", "transparent");
                $("#suburb-icon").css("background-size", "100%");
            }
        }
    }

    export class MultipleSelectAreaGetter extends AreaGetter {
        _selectedAreas = ko.observableArray([]);
    }

    export class SingleSelectAreaGetter extends AreaGetter {



    }

    export enum Type {
        Region,
        Town,
        Suburb
    }
}
```

Then when I try to use it in view_models/search_view_model.ts:

```
class SearchFilterViewModel {
    _regionGetter: Area.SingleSelectAreaGetter;
    _townGetter: SingleSelectAreaGetter;
    _suburbGetter: MultipleSelectAreaGetter;
    _categories: KnockoutObservableArray<Category>;
    _selectedCategories: KnockoutObservableArray<Category>;

    constructor() {
        this._categories = ko.observableArray([
            new Category("Vegan Meat", 1), 
            new Category("Vegan Dairy", 2), 
            new Category("Confectionary", 3),
            new Category("Baking", 4),
            new Category("Dessert", 5),
            new Category("Restaurants", 6),
            new Category("Grocers", 7)
        ]);
        this._selectedCategories = ko.observableArray([]);
        this._regionGetter = new Area.SingleSelectAreaGetter(Area.Type.Region);
        this._townGetter = new SingleSelectAreaGetter(Type.Town);
        this._suburbGetter = new MultipleSelectAreaGetter(Type.Suburb);
        this._regionGetter.getAreas("2186224");
        //this._regionGetter._selectedAreaGeonameId.subscribe(this._townGetter.getAreas.bind(this._townGetter));
        //this._townGetter._selectedArea.subscribe(this._suburbGetter.getAreas.bind(this._suburbGetter));
    }
}
```

It doesn't recognise "Area".

How do I make search_view_model recognise the Area module?

Would I do something like `import { Area } from "./models/area_getter";`?

This has an error in the import statement saying

> cannot find module Area

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "outDir":"js/"
    },
  "exclude": [
    "bower_components",
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]  
}
```

Comment: What does tsconfig.json look like?  Are you using commonjs?  If AMD/es6 you need to import the module.  Do you specify and "out"?
E.g. https://github.com/ca0v/ags-lab/blob/master/tsconfig.json

Comment: @CoreyAlix I just added the tsconfig to the question.

Comment: I think "outDir" is not correct.  You want it all in a single file?  Try "out".  Otherwise you need to import.

Comment: @CoreyAlix I don't think I would want the js in one file as it would be a bit harder to find specific lines of code when debugging wouldn't it?

Comment: Then you need to import.  See f1 & f2 examples in answer below.

Answer (score -1):

Try

1. Removing the "export module Area {"
2. import Area = require("./models/area_getter")

That eliminates the explicit module name and lets you name it within the import.

So f1:

```
export interface iGetAreas {
}

export abstract class AreaGetter implements iGetAreas {
}

export class MultipleSelectAreaGetter extends AreaGetter {
}

export class SingleSelectAreaGetter extends AreaGetter {
}
```

f2:

```
import Area = require("./f1");

class SearchFilterViewModel {
    _regionGetter: Area.SingleSelectAreaGetter;
    _townGetter: Area.SingleSelectAreaGetter;
    _suburbGetter: Area.MultipleSelectAreaGetter;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean I should try not even having a module anywhere? Is that import just of a class?

Comment: Not a class, just an anonymous module.  And maybe you should be importing "ko" too?

import ko = require("./path/to/knockout");

export interface iGetAreas {
    _areasList: Array<any>;
    _areas: KnockoutObservableArray<string>;
    getAreas(geonameId: string): void;
}

Comment: I'm getting these errors: > system-csp-production.src.js:3217 Uncaught TypeError: Multiple anonymous System.register calls in the same module file.t @ system-csp-production.src.js:3217l.register @ system-csp-production.src.js:3217(anonymous function) @ search_filter_view_model.js:1
bootstrap_app.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: SearchFilterViewModel is not defined

My import statement has no red squigglies. I use `import Area = require("../models/area_getter.ts");` Do you know why I have the errors?

Comment: No, I use requirejs and AMD so I'm not sure but try removing the .ts extension from the import.  Just "../models/area_getter".